# custom permalink/shortlink with base62 encoded post ID

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I want my post-links to look like /%post_id62%_%postname%/ where %post_id62% is the post ID in base62 encoding (e.g. http://example.com/y9Rlf_test/) and my shortlinks to consist of /%post_id62% only (e.g. http://example.com/y9Rlf). This is what i've got so far (in my `functions.php`) which obviously doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'init', 'yoyo_init' );
function yoyo_init() {
  add_rewrite_tag( '%post_id62%', '([A-Za-z0-9]+)' );
}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules','yoyo_generate_rewrite_rules');
function yoyo_generate_rewrite_rules($yoyo_rewrite) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $new_rules['/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?p=' .
    base622dec($wp_rewrite->preg_index(1));  // DOESNT WORK OF COURSE (executed only once when rewrite_rules are generated)
  $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge($new_rules, $wp_rewrite->rules);
}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'yoyo_post_link', 10, 2 );
function yoyo_post_link( $permalink, $post ) {
  if ( false !== strpos( $permalink, '%post_id62%' ) ) {
    $post_id62 = dec2base62( $post->ID );
    $permalink = str_replace( '%post_id62%', $post_id62, $permalink );
  }
  return $permalink;
}

add_filter('pre_get_shortlink', 'yoyo_custom_shortlink', 10, 4);
function yoyo_custom_shortlink($false, $post_id, $context, $allow_slugs) {
  global $wp_query;
  if($post_id or ($context == 'query' and $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id())) {
    return home_url('/' . dec2base62($post_id));
  }
  return false;
}

function dec2base62($number) {
  $digits = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';  $string = '';  while($number > 0) { $string = $digits[$number % 62] . $string;  $number = floor($number / 62); }
  return $string;
}
function base622dec($string) {
  $digits = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';  $number = 0;  while(strlen($string) and ($number *= 62 or strlen($string))) { $number += strpos($digits, $string[0]);  $string  = substr($string, 1); }
  return $number;
}
```

Any idea how to tackle the problem?
Bonus points for avoiding the -N slug suffix when there's another post with the same title created (which might be avoided actually when setting the link structure to "/%post_id62%_%postname%/" but in order to have the shortlink functionality it should be "/%post_id62%" I guess; cf. [Turn off %postname% auto-incrementing?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7922))!
Thanks!

Comment: -N suffix is created to make unique slugs. Slugs are meant to be unique and are created from the title, so when you have same title for 2 posts, the same slug is created for 2nd post and then -N is applied to make it unique. If you don't want -N then modify the slug just below the title while creating your new post.

Comment: @Hameedullah Not true when using something like /%post_id%-%postname%/ according to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7922/turn-off-postname-auto-incrementing/7949#7949

Comment: Not true. Did you try creating posts with same name while using %post_id%? It adds -N after the slug, even if you are using %post_id% based permalinks. I just tried this on vanilla WP3.2 and WP3.1.3.

Comment: But the second option given in Michael's answer will work for you.

Comment: Seems I've misunderstood the first option Mike gave. Seems he's wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only made a mistake in the final step, when you convert the base62-encoded ID back to a decimal ID. You should not do this by changing the rewrite rules, as they are only patterns, not actual rules per post.

What you want is take an incoming URL, let WordPress parse it using the rewrite rules, but then before it is passed to the query engine, check for the `post_id62` variable and set the actual `p` (post id) variable based on it. You can do this in the `request` filter, which [is applied in `WP::parse_request()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L299).

```
add_action( 'request', 'wpse22253_request' );
function wpse22253_request( $query_vars )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'post_id62', $query_vars ) ) {
        $query_vars['p'] = base622dec( $query_vars['post_id62'] );
    }
    return $query_vars;
}
```

However, this will not solve the `postname-N` problem. WordPress will still call `wp_unique_post_slug` on the `post_name` field, and `post_name` will not include the `post_id62` part (since the database is independent of the rewrite rules). As Mike suggested in [the followup comments to his answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7922/turn-off-postname-auto-incrementing/7949#7949), you should either figure out a way to include the `post_id62` part in the `post_name` field, or (and this might be the better way) ignore the `%postname%` part in the URL and just slap a *postname-with-stripped-number-suffix* string at the end.

You will also run into issues with your shortlinks, since they have the same format (any letter or digit) as a page. Is `/banana/` a page with the title "Banana" or a shortlink to the post with ID 34440682410 - which is `banana` in your base-62 encoding?

Comment: Thanks a lot! No issues with shortlinks vs pages here; my site doesn’t have pages. No need for author-, category-, ...-pages either, but yes, have to change /feed/ to /_feed/. What annoys me is that the year pattern ([0-9]{4}) jumps in where ((19|20)[0-9]{2}) really should do it. I guess I want to get rid of all those patterns.